# Posting to self servlet creating an infinite loop

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, post

I am trying to develop a servlet page that will display a form and the user will fill in the form and post to the servlet itself (problem). I pasted all code below. When I call the servlet the page is displayed ok and I can fill in the form however when I click submit and post it, the programs enters a loop where the mysql insert command runs indefinitely and I am forced to stop the program.

The problem seems to be coming from the line:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/problem").include(request, response);
```

However this is the only way I see to call the servlet again after I post the page but somehow this is creating a program loop. Any idea why this is the case?

Below is my servlet:

```
@WebServlet(description = "Problem Page", urlPatterns = { "/problem" })
public class ProblemPage extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public ProblemPage() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String problemID = request.getParameter("pbid");
    String option = request.getParameter("opt");
    String productID = request.getParameter("pdid");

    if(problemID==null && option==null && productID==null) {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            for(String printLine:(new Problem()).printProblemAdd()) {
                out.print(printLine);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if(problemID!=null && option!=null && productID==null) {
        if(option.equals("edit")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("problem").include(request, response);  
        } else if(option.equals("del")) {

        } else {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("<p>Page is invalid.</p>");
        }

    } else if(problemID==null && option==null && productID!=null) {
        //Lists problems for product

        Problem problem = new Problem(productID);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            for(String printLine:problem.print()) {
                out.print(printLine);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        //Page is invalid
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<p>Page is invalid.</p>");
    }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String Url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
      String DbName = "knowledge";
      String Driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String UserName = "root"; 
      String Password = "";
      Connection Conn = null;         

    try {
        Class.forName(Driver).newInstance();
          Conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(Url + DbName,UserName,Password);
          //St = (Statement) Conn.createStatement();

          String mysqlQuery = "INSERT INTO problems (ID,productID,description) VALUES (?,?,?);";
          PreparedStatement updateStatement = (PreparedStatement) Conn.prepareStatement(mysqlQuery);
          updateStatement.setInt(1,0);
          updateStatement.setString(2, request.getParameter("productid"));
          updateStatement.setString(3, request.getParameter("description"));
          int Res = updateStatement.executeUpdate();    

          request.setAttribute("message", Res>0?"Record added: " + request.getParameter("description"):"Record failed");


          Conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
          try {
              Conn.close();
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/problem").include(request, response);  
}
}
```

Comment: bad design! You should move back to JSP/FE for user to fill in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the final line is trying to call the same handler with the same request, which is causing a loop? [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)